# Sorting an element containing a certain string value to a different position within an typescript array

Tags: arrays, typescript, sorting, typescript2.0

for those of you who have answered and read my previous question, gratitude is great. 
This question is a follow up.

Right now I have the following snippet

`public async personNews(serviceBranch?: string[]): Promise<INews> {
    const fetchResult: IPersonNewsFetchResultEntry[] = await this._get('api/person/news/', newsSchema, true) as IPersonNewsFetchResultEntry[];
    const serviceBranches: string[] =

      fetchResult.filter((entry, index, array) => { 
        return array.findIndex(({unitID}) => entry.unitID === unitID) === index;
        }).map(entry => entry.unitID);`

What I would like is for serviceBranch to be included in my filter in such a way that the elements from the newly created array get the serviceBranch parameter on top or in a place of my choosing.
So for instance right now my array will look like [TRY, PLO, OMO, MNY, WER, TQA, MNB].
The serviceBranch parameter will be WER so then I would like my array to be [TRY, WER, OMO, MNY, etc... ]  The most important part is moving that element to the top 3.

What would be the best way for me to achieve this result. 
I've been looking in sort function but none of what I have read give me the desired result. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the "best" way, but a straightforward way is to use the [`findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) method of an array to locate the item you're trying to move, and then use the [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method twice to remove and reinsert the element in the place you care about.  Here's a possible implementation:

```
function moveToPos<T>(arr: T[], pred: (x: T) => boolean, pos: number) {
    const curPos = arr.findIndex(pred);
    if (curPos < 0) return;
    arr.splice(pos, 0, ...arr.splice(curPos, 1));
}
```

So `moveToPos()` takes an array, a predicate to locate the element, and a new position for the element.  Let's try it on an array of strings:

```
const a = ["TRY", "PLO", "OMO", "MNY", "WER", "TQA", "MNB"];
console.log(a.join(",")); // TRY,PLO,OMO,MNY,WER,TQA,MNB 
moveToPos(a, s => s === "WER", 0); // move WER to first position
console.log(a.join(",")); // WER,TRY,PLO,OMO,MNY,TQA,MNB 
moveToPos(a, s => s === "WER", 1); // move WER to second position
console.log(a.join(",")); // TRY,WER,PLO,OMO,MNY,TQA,MNB 
moveToPos(a, s => s === "WER", 2); // move WER to third position
console.log(a.join(",")); // TRY,PLO,WER,OMO,MNY,TQA,MNB
```

Looks good to me.  But maybe you want to just swap two elements instead of shifting the array around?  That's possible also:

```
function moveToPos<T>(arr: T[], pred: (x: T) => boolean, pos: number) {
    pos = Math.max(Math.min(pos, arr.length - 1), 0);
    const curPos = arr.findIndex(pred);
    if (curPos < 0) return;
    [arr[curPos], arr[pos]] = [arr[pos], arr[curPos]]; // destructuring
    // or you could do the less tricky way
    // const tmp = arr[curPos];
    // arr[curPos] = arr[pos];
    // arr[pos] = tmp;
}
```

with accordingly different results:

```
const a = ["TRY", "PLO", "OMO", "MNY", "WER", "TQA", "MNB"];
console.log(a.join(",")); // TRY,PLO,OMO,MNY,WER,TQA,MNB 
moveToPos(a, s => s === "WER", 0); // move WER to first position 
console.log(a.join(",")); // WER,PLO,OMO,MNY,TRY,TQA,MNB 
moveToPos(a, s => s === "WER", 1); // move WER to second position
console.log(a.join(",")); // PLO,WER,OMO,MNY,TRY,TQA,MNB 
moveToPos(a, s => s === "WER", 2); // move WER to third position
console.log(a.join(",")); // PLO,OMO,WER,MNY,TRY,TQA,MNB
```

Note that there are all kinds of edge cases: what if your predicate matches no elements? (then nothing gets moved; is that what you want?)  What if your predicate matches more than one element? (then the first one gets moved; is that what you want?) What if your new position is outside of the array (then whatever `splice()` does with that is what happens) What happens to the rest of the elements in the array that you didn't ask about (they move around in some way either by shifting or swapping) so you should be careful and decide exactly what you want, and this could affect the implementation.

Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!

---

Update: if all you care about is moving elements that match a predicate to the front of the list while leaving the rest alone and additionally that you want to use the array's `sort()` method, you could do something like this:

```
function moveToFront<T>(arr: T[], findPred: (x: T) => boolean) {
    arr.sort((x, y) => +findPred(y) - +findPred(x))
}
```

You need to use a predicate in general to identify the thing to move, since equality operators only work for primitives and identical object references.  Anyway, this results in:

```
const a = ["TRY", "PLO", "OMO", "MNY", "WER", "TQA", "MNB"];
console.log(a.join(",")); // TRY,PLO,OMO,MNY,WER,TQA,MNB 
moveToFront(a, s => s === "WER");
console.log(a.join(",")); // WER,TRY,PLO,OMO,MNY,TQA,MNB
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBlGAbAlopBvAsAFBIlIBmArsPAC6YD2wSY9AbhACr0AK9UAPBwB8AChAAncQC4kHANoBdADRIY4iABMZIgB4yOASiQBeIUgBG9eugghgKmHxnAKYcxHFGCxUr-iMoGiR4CnFeKBMkCXEAOjJMYA0ASUSIHRE1TQMAbiJfX0wyJBEQsL4kfiQABiN1GlDgXJ98qMkY2CxEDL4VKpUYgej2jGwIEtDwlQBGAxy80gBfInmSf2BAqMi5ACIOACUATW2Vbe4AGQB5Y6Rti4BZK5O7gDkjk4B1AFE9692ARQAgr8XgAhbYKJp+ALWCAxdD0ADmYhiACt6AkRMdtrNskgAPR42SHJTnC5Ke5kl4HJRfPZKDiApSgpArZhsTg8PhiFQRUxIXnGYw3WnXGq4gls9hIWlIGj0ciYcQbRxQTB0Rgs5rBaE2OGI5FojFYnH4wm0+nE0nkh5M170xnM1ksdhccLc-kmMwCoXbEXTHKmyXIGVy-kQNYaVR8NUMYCstZQGF6pEgVHo4CYpTYgMS-bU81Wim26kMgG2kGa3zOjlukA8z0ewU+v1IABMOcJ1el31l8poAAtFZGVTHGPGdbD4Sm00asybc5bLjTvtbKXbS+XNUQloQiKBILAEMgUAB3EAwPCsyjUdVMauuviCUTRfSKBzqLTFPSyIx8ywwuwHCcJAXDcDwvFZXwVUiO4QAHGIwBAdJYPgsAMRVFQhhsYAEQHJAAFokBmXo5i1KF1iCUpwkiIZ4kSFINDSDIP1IloSEKYoqPKSoaiQOoGkhNi5GiOQuKgZRWnEOQVQUBQthEmTMMkUSJj4WTBJIHdxwozYhR2PNflJX4KWBV5fhbf4gSeZ4wQhbTE11KcDXTTNs3FQk8xJJciypZc6Q3R0tXvTkoHdXkvRMQVhW+UUOyDbs9l7BUlSCEdb0rUgEyTJzU0NDNjTigtvJtXzPICmyMpIYLa3rPlvWin5-Xc+KQ3lKBw0YYdo1vezsv1XKXIK5qrXNHz12JcqKyddkH1CutGwipsGuudtmq7VrZUHcQutVHqtSyxz+pnfK5ziwsbXNUqJodCrlkIHdNX3aA4BwFB6HEIJvF8a9aFjIMuAAMXERgaCfMRJFfCS6I0bgP20b9DAbf8bDsCCyNIIZEw+kRdBUABPX8zAAamh2HNBEAmCKQEmEhhj9dFmVktP2gIghALZdkOQzLmMh5TLeZaTlLUzbI07V1j66c8tc+cPMXMkxvzFdJsq-76CBkGwoberfRi1jMonZNnNnNzA3NTzzrXEsbpBbcgA)

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I will play around with what you've given me.

Comment: On hindsight, is it possible to just do some sort of simple comparison and using this in the sort function?
For instance   calling  .sort(pushToFirstPos)
private pushToFirstPos(serviceBranch){
//logic to push serviceBranch to first position.
}

Comment: Updated my answer, but I don't know what equality metric you're using so `pushToFirstPos()` probably needs to take a predicate and not a value.  I'm also not sure why you want to use `sort()` instead of `findIndex()` but there you go.  Good luck!